# sql experssion - select from another databass

Tags: sql, mysql

i have column in a table and i wanna assign it to another select query

my err look like this

my code

```
ALTER TABLE `pishfactor`.`list` 
ADD COLUMN `darsadza` VARCHAR(45) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SELECT  *    
FROM pishfactor.zayeatdarsad WHERE `name` = `type` ) VIRTUAL AFTER   
`type`;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

Note 1: your name values in your objects must be in quotes.

Note 2: inside your mapped data your markup needs to be wrapped in either a containing element or a [React fragment](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment).

Note 3: ideally you want to add an id to your objects that you can use as a key on the wrapping element (rather than using the `map` index).

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {
  return (
    <main>
      {data.slice(0, 2).map(obj => {
        return (
          <section key={obj.id}>
            <h1>{obj.name}</h1>
            <h2>{obj.age}</h2>
          </section>
        );
      })} 
    </main>
  );
}

const data = [{id:1,name:'john',age:20},{id:2,name:'jack',age:24},{id:3,name:'rose',age:26},{id:4,name:'david',age:40}];

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Example data={data} />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, this is more like a programming thing, there's lots of ways. Other than the `slice`, which could be the best safe way. If you just start programming, you can try the following as well.

```
[0,1].map(i => ( 
  <>
    <h1>{array[i].name}</h1>
    <h2>{array[i].age}</h1>
  </>
))
```

As I said, this is programming, do whatever to make it work then. For example, just copy paste twice that'll solve your problem as well. Or do a loop and skip when index is bigger than two.

Comment: ye but it is i react and its matter to use best way